# Redirecting posts in Wordpress to a specific page

Tags: wordpress, loops, posts

I created a page so that it would appear in my navigation menu. This page would however be my posts page (i.e. all posts would go here) and would also be my front page.

I am unable to find anything other than editing the 'Home' in the theme file (none of the themes I tried had the 'Home' editable).

In other words, I'm looking for something that would redirect all of my posts as a stream into my homepage that also has a link in the navigation menu.

I tried looking at a lot of places for help in this, however I couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Compete this sentence - I want a page that...

Comment: Oh alright! Here goes:
I want a page that 
(a) Wordpress would redirect all my posts to,
(b) be my frontpage and 
(c) have a link in the navigation menu.

Answer (score 1):

Under Settings -> Reading edit "Front page displays" to display "Your Latest Posts" then provide a link in your navigation menu to the root, mysite.com

If you want to style it you can use the editor to change the appearance.